# What to use exactly to navigate data between views/controllers in ionic

Tags: angularjs, view, ionic-framework

I've started developing a simple application :

[image: my first ionic app]

in the first view I'm retreiving all the games, and the other view i'm retreivig the game details according to the game id.

I didn't link the two pages yet.

this is what i'm facing as problem. i'm confused ! should I use ion-view ?? or I should use a normal page

for each view I have a controller which look almost like :

```
.controller('tomorrowmatches', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.myappbackend/ofc/matches?date=2015-05-03")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.matches = response;

            }

        });

})
```

and how to pass data from conroller to another, in my example I wanna pass the game.id as shwon on the screenshot.

if you need more details just let me know. I just need someone to make things clear for me, and if there is an example it would be fantastic.

Comment: as @aorfevre suggest earlier read the [docs](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/) and you'll find out all your answers.

Comment: I've already did that

Comment: look at that : https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu/
The solution in your case is using : ui-router params (with id) OR using services to store data shared from controller to controller

Answer (score 1):

To pass data to another view you can use the $state and $stateParams services.

Example

**Controller 1** (sends the data)

```
.controller('MyCtrl1', function($scope, $state) {
        $scope.selectedData = function(selectedId) {
            $state.go('yourState', { id: selectedId });
        };
    })
```

**Controller 2** (gets the data)

```
.controller('YourCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
        if ($stateParams.id) {
            $scope.yourParam = $stateParams.id;
        }

        // Do anything you want with the ID inside $scope.yourParam
    })
```

**app.js**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('init', {
                url: "/init",
                templateUrl: "templates/init.html",
                controller: "MyCtrl1"
            })
            .state('yourState', {
                url: "/yourState?id",
                templateUrl: "templates/your-template.html",
                controller: "YourCtrl"
            })

        // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/init');
    })
```

As you can see in the state  `yourState` I assigned an `id` as a parameter. This parameter will be checked if exists by `YourCtrl`, if it exists assign to scope and then do whatever you want with it.

Remember to set the parameter options in your app.js route configuration.

Check the [ui-router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) for more info on this. You have more ways to send data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need the ion view as a container for your views/templates..

```
<body ng-app="myapp">    
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

then on your app.js you need to configure your routing..

```
// Ionic Starter App

angular.module('myapp', ['ionic', 'myapp.controllers', 'myapp.services', 'myapp.directives'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  // $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;

  $stateProvider

  //Page1
  .state('page1', {
    url: "/page1",
    templateUrl: "templates/page1.html",
    controller: "Page1Controller"
  })

  //Page2
  .state('page2', {
    url: "/page2",
    templateUrl: "templates/page2.html",
    controller: "Page2Controller",
  })

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page1');

});
```

Note: Make sure that all dependencies for ionic are included on your folder and called on your index.html..

Hope this helps :)